# Collections.sort() not working with class that implements Comparable or when using Comparator Java

Tags: java, generics, interface

So as far as I can tell, I have correctly implemented the compareTo method in my class but when Collections.sort() is called, the list does not appear to get sorted. I have tried to troubleshoot using ArrayList to make sure I am implementing everything right, but no success. I have no success with Comparators either. Please, for the love of God, someone help me!!

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class CreditCard implements Comparable<CreditCard>, Serializable {

    //data fields
    private String lastName, firstName, PAN;
    private Date expDate;

    //use of SimpleDateFormat to convert strings/dates
    private String pattern = "MM/yy";
    private SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

    //Constructor
    public CreditCard(String firstName, String lastName, String PAN, String date) {

        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.PAN = PAN;
        try {
            this.expDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Getters
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getPAN() {
        return PAN;
    }

    public Date getExpDate() {
        return expDate;
    }

    //Overridden methods
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Name on Card: %s %s\nCard #: %s\nExp Date: %s\n",
                firstName,lastName,PAN,simpleDateFormat.format(expDate));
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CreditCard o) {
        if (this.getPAN().compareTo(o.getPAN()) == -1) {
            return -1;
        } else if (this.getPAN().compareToIgnoreCase(o.getPAN()) == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

comparators

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class DateCompare implements Comparator<CreditCard>, Serializable{
    @Override
    public int compare(CreditCard o1, CreditCard o2) {
        if (o1.getExpDate().compareTo(o2.getExpDate()) == -1) {
            return -1;
        } else if ((o1.getExpDate().compareTo(o2.getExpDate()) == 0)) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class NameCompare implements Comparator<CreditCard>, Serializable {
    @Override
    public int compare(CreditCard o1, CreditCard o2) {
        if (o1.getLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getLastName()) == 0) {
            if (o1.getFirstName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getFirstName()) == 0) {
                return 0;
            } else if (o1.getFirstName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getFirstName()) == -1) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        } else if (o1.getLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getLastName()) == -1) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Main

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CreditPayments {

    //instantiate an ArrayList to hold credit cards
    private ArrayList<CreditCard> list = new ArrayList<>();

    //add credit cards to the list of cards
    public void add(CreditCard creditCard) {
        list.add(creditCard);
    }

    //reset the list of credit cards
    public void reset() {
        list.clear();
    }

    //Sort and print by PAN
    public ArrayList<CreditCard> printByPAN() {
        Collections.sort(list);
        for (CreditCard cc: list) {
         System.out.println(cc);
        }
        return list;
    }

    //Sort and print by Name
    public ArrayList<CreditCard> printByName() {
        Collections.sort(list, new NameCompare());
        for (CreditCard cc: list) {
            System.out.println(cc);
        }
        return list;
    }

    //Sort and print by expiration date
    public ArrayList<CreditCard> printByDate() {
        Collections.sort(list, new DateCompare());
        for (CreditCard cc: list) {
            System.out.println(cc);
        }
        return list;}

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<CreditCard> payments = new ArrayList<>();
            payments.add( new CreditCard("bob", "smith", "1234567890", "03/17") );
            payments.add( new CreditCard("bill", "smith", "9999999999", "04/18") );
            payments.add( new CreditCard("bob", "smyth", "1111111111", "05/19") );
        Collections.sort(payments);
        for (CreditCard s: payments) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparator/comparable overrides defined by you are based on String#compareTo implementation. According to the [original documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-) the compareTo method on a String returns a positive number, **a negative number** or a zero based on the lexicographical ordering. The negative number is **not necessarily -1** as you seem to be checking in your code. So even if a String might precede another lexicographically, your code would only order it if the return value of String#compareTo is -1 (and not if it is any other negative value).

Try using the following code :

```
@Override public int compareTo(CreditCard o) { 
    return this.getPAN().compareTo(o.getPAN());
 }
```

Comment: This was the problem. Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Collections.sort(list)` not `list.sort(null)`.

If you look at the doco for [list.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) you'll see that it sorts using the supplied comparator. You're supplying `null` which (I assume) has the effect of leaving your list unsorted.

[Collections.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) on the other hand, will sort the list according to the natural ordering of its elements (as specified by your implementation of `Comparable`).

Your implementation of `CreditCard.compareTo()` can be simplified as:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(CreditCard o) {
    return this.PAN.compareTo(o.PAN);
}
```

You currently use both `compareTo()` and `compareToIgnoreCase()`. Pick one.

Comment: I have used Collections.sort() originally, It had the same effect

Comment: @RyanOtero Which particular entity is failing to sort?

Answer (score 1):

You should add your comparator to ArrayList:

```
 Collections.sort(payments, new NameCompare());
```

Answer (score 0):

Only getByPAN is not sorting correctly. For it to sort correctly, you need to add a new `Comparator`. Adding the updated code and output.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;

public class CreditPayments {

    //instantiate an ArrayList to hold credit cards
    private ArrayList<CreditCard> list = new ArrayList<>();

    //add credit cards to the list of cards
    public void add(CreditCard creditCard) {
        list.add(creditCard);
    }

    //reset the list of credit cards
    public void reset() {
        list.clear();
    }

    //Sort and print by PAN
    public ArrayList<CreditCard> printByPAN() {
        Collections.sort(list, new PanCompare());
        for (CreditCard cc: list) {
            System.out.println(cc);
        }
        return list;
    }

    //Sort and print by Name
    public ArrayList<CreditCard> printByName() {
        Collections.sort(list, new NameCompare());
        for (CreditCard cc: list) {
            System.out.println(cc);
        }
        return list;
    }

    //Sort and print by expiration date
    public ArrayList<CreditCard> printByDate() {
        Collections.sort(list, new DateCompare());
        for (CreditCard cc: list) {
            System.out.println(cc);
        }
        return list;}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<CreditCard> payments = new ArrayList<>();
        payments.add( new CreditCard("bob", "smith", "1234567890", "03/17") );
        payments.add( new CreditCard("bill", "smith", "9999999999", "04/18") );
        payments.add( new CreditCard("bob", "smyth", "1111111111", "05/19") );


        CreditPayments s = new CreditPayments();
        s.list = payments;
        System.out.println("print by name");
        s.printByName();
        System.out.println("------------------------------");

        System.out.println("print by date");
        s.printByDate();
        System.out.println("------------------------------");

        System.out.println("print by pan");
        s.printByPAN();
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
    }
}

class CreditCard implements Comparable<CreditCard>, Serializable {

    //data fields
    private String lastName, firstName, PAN;
    private Date expDate;

    //use of SimpleDateFormat to convert strings/dates
    private String pattern = "MM/yy";
    private SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

    //Constructor
    public CreditCard(String firstName, String lastName, String PAN, String date) {

        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.PAN = PAN;
        try {
            this.expDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Getters
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getPAN() {
        return PAN;
    }

    public Date getExpDate() {
        return expDate;
    }

    //Overridden methods
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Name on Card: %s %s\nCard #: %s\nExp Date: %s\n",
                firstName,lastName,PAN,simpleDateFormat.format(expDate));
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CreditCard o) {
        if (this.getPAN().compareTo(o.getPAN()) == -1) {
            return -1;
        } else if (this.getPAN().compareToIgnoreCase(o.getPAN()) == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

class DateCompare implements Comparator<CreditCard>, Serializable {
    @Override
    public int compare(CreditCard o1, CreditCard o2) {
        if (o1.getExpDate().compareTo(o2.getExpDate()) == -1) {
            return -1;
        } else if ((o1.getExpDate().compareTo(o2.getExpDate()) == 0)) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

class NameCompare implements Comparator<CreditCard>, Serializable {
    @Override
    public int compare(CreditCard o1, CreditCard o2) {
        if (o1.getLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getLastName()) == 0) {
            if (o1.getFirstName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getFirstName()) == 0) {
                return 0;
            } else if (o1.getFirstName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getFirstName()) == -1) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        } else if (o1.getLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getLastName()) == -1) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

class PanCompare implements Comparator<CreditCard>, Serializable {
    @Override
    public int compare(CreditCard o1, CreditCard o2) {
        return o1.getPAN().compareTo(o2.getPAN());
    }
}
```

The output,

```
print by name
Name on Card: bob smith
Card #: 1234567890
Exp Date: 03/17

Name on Card: bill smith
Card #: 9999999999
Exp Date: 04/18

Name on Card: bob smyth
Card #: 1111111111
Exp Date: 05/19

------------------------------
print by date
Name on Card: bob smith
Card #: 1234567890
Exp Date: 03/17

Name on Card: bill smith
Card #: 9999999999
Exp Date: 04/18

Name on Card: bob smyth
Card #: 1111111111
Exp Date: 05/19

------------------------------
print by pan
Name on Card: bob smyth
Card #: 1111111111
Exp Date: 05/19

Name on Card: bob smith
Card #: 1234567890
Exp Date: 03/17

Name on Card: bill smith
Card #: 9999999999
Exp Date: 04/18

------------------------------
```